# How to extract Javascript array information and insert into DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Initially, I have the following:

```
<ul id="my_List">
...
</ul>
```

Using Javascript, I want to generate "li" elements within that ul block that use values for the text information from the array.

For example, I have a template:

```
<li>
  <div>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="icon"></span>
      <span class="text">[PLACEHOLDER HERE]</span>
      <span class="icon"></span>
      <span class="icon large"></span>
      <br/>
      <span class="information">[PLACEHOLDER HERE]</span>
      <hr />
    </a>
  </div>
</li>
```

and I'm trying to figure out how to parse the information from my Javascript array into the [PLACEHOLDER HERE] blocks while still applying the whole template (all the internal tags and classes) in some kind of for loop. Is there a quick way of doing this or will I have to do a series of appends and whatnot to achieve my goal here?

Comment: There are many libraries  that do templating for you. Examples range from Mustache / Handlebars to using Underscore or Lodash. Is there a reason for wanting to do this from scratch?

Comment: you have any specifics on how your js array looks like?

Comment: @webeno web_info = {
    "info": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "hello,
            "target": [2,5]
        }, etc...

Comment: if you can use es2015 features, take a look at template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: only chrome supports it as of this time, but this is shadow dom all the way https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array mapping is another option

```js
var arr = [
  { a: 'foo', b: 'bar' },
  { a: 'foo 2', b: 'bar 2' },
];

var html = arr.map(function(item) {
 return '<li>' +
     '<span>' + item.a + '<span>' + 
            '<span>' + item.a + '<span>' + 
         '</li>';
}).join('');

document.getElementById('#list').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<ul id="#list"></ul>
```

Comment: Almost exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to create a model. Continue like this and create a model like you want.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 window.onload = function() {
function createTable(tableData) {
  var ul = document.getElementById('my_List');
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var ahref = document.createElement('a');

  tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
      var cell = document.createElement('span');
      cell.innerHTML = cellData;
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    ahref.appendChild(row);
  });

  div.appendChild(ahref);
  li.appendChild(div);
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

createTable([["row 1, cell 1", "row 1, cell 2"], ["row 2, cell 1", "row 2, cell 2"]]);

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have an HTML element you want to use as a template -- simply clone it and populate as needed.

```js
$("#create-more").on("click", function() {
  // First, save references...
  var myContentPane = $(".content-pane");
  var myText = $(".form-text").val();
  var myInfo = $(".form-info").val();

  // This is a clone of our hidden template
  var myTemplate = $("#template").clone();

  // Replace placeholders in the template...
  myTemplate.attr("id", "");
  myTemplate.find(".text").text(myText);
  myTemplate.find(".information").text(myInfo);

  // Now we use the template!
  myContentPane.append(myTemplate);
});
```

```css
#template {
  display: none;
}
label {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="text-stuff">Some text:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-text" />
  <label for="information">Some Info:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-info" />
  <button id="create-more">
    Create more
  </button>
</form>
<div id="template">
  <a href="#"><span class="icon" </span>
    <span class="text">[PLACEHOLDER HERE]</span>
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="icon large"></span>
    <br/>
    <span class="information">[PLACEHOLDER HERE]</span>
    <hr />
  </a>
</div>
<section class="content-pane">
</section>
```

Comment: you haven't really touched the way values from the array would get into the template, which is the may question of the OP, I think, otherwise I believe you seem to be on the right path here...

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this problem from scratch can get very messy; I'd recommend you make use of available libraries.

**lodash** has a great solution called `_.template`. [Check out the docs here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#template).

```
// constructing string like this for readability
var li = [
    '<li>',
    '<div><%=id%></div>',
    '<div><%=name%></div>',
    '</li>'
].join('');

var liTemplate = _.template(li);

var liOne = liTemplate({ id: '1', name: 'Hello' }); // => "<li><div>1</div><div>Hello</div></li>"
var liTwo = liTemplate({ id: '2', name: 'World' }); // => "<li><div>2</div><div>World</div></li>"
```

EDIT: In order to get those strings into your DOM, you could do the following:

```
var ul = document.getElementById('my_list');
ul.innerHTML = liOne + liTwo;
```